# Read database connection details from application.yml

Tags: bdd, karate

I am currently connecting to database to run my karate scenarios by having the db user id and password in the karate-config.j  file.
I already have the database user id, password and url mentioned in the corresponding environment application-.yml file and trying to find a way to pass this to karate-config.js dynamically at runtime. Any leads here please ?